# windows DLL function call external exe file invalid

Tags: c++, dll, exe

Compile Env：Visual Studio 2010

I have write an program and compile to createFile.exe file

```
ofstream file;
file.open("C:\\test.txt", ios::app);
file << "hello test "<< argv[0] << argv[1] << argv[2] <<endl;
file.close();
```

Then I create an dll file and this is the function i call createFile.exe in dll

```
if (!CreateProcess(L"C:\\", L"createFile.exe hello test", NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
    printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
    return 0;
}
```

The Process has been created(i can get it's processid and threadid) and CreateProcess return success(0), but test.txt has not been create.

How could i fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have write-permissions in C:\? Do you, in your actual program, check that the file opened successfully?

Comment: You cannot create files in the root directory of the C: drive unless your program runs UAC elevated so it acquired admin rights.  That it worked anyway strongly suggests that your program does not have a manifest that declares it compatible with UAC.  That works, your file is created in isolated storage.

Comment: Thanks! the problem is that i have no write-permissions in C:\

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you should use CreateProcess :

```
STARTUPINFO         siStartupInfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcessInfo;

memset(&siStartupInfo, 0, sizeof(siStartupInfo));
memset(&piProcessInfo, 0, sizeof(piProcessInfo));

siStartupInfo.cb = sizeof(siStartupInfo);

if(CreateProcess("c:\\winnt\\notepad.exe",       // Application name
                 " example.txt",                 // Additional application arguments
                 NULL,
                 NULL,
                 FALSE,
                 CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE,
                 NULL,
                 NULL,
                 &siStartupInfo,
                 &piProcessInfo) == FALSE)
  // Could not start application

// Wait until application has terminated
WaitForSingleObject(piProcessInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);

// Close process and thread handles
::CloseHandle(piProcessInfo.hThread);
::CloseHandle(piProcessInfo.hProcess);
```

If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.